# How to create a boolean datatype in AWS DynamoDB Read/Write operations using DynamoDB table annotations

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I have created a class pojo class in java to create/update items in aws dynamodb when i was trying to create/update an item in dynamodb it is working fine but the column created in dynamodb datatype seems to be string instead of boolean. I have tried below annotations but whenever row created datatype seems to be string instead of boolean.

```
@DynamoDBConvertedBool(value = Format.true_false)
@DynamoDBConvertedBool(DynamoDBConvertedBool.Format.true_false)
```

**DynamoDb class.java**

```
@DynamoDBConvertedBool(value = Format.true_false)
public boolean isDailyconsolidated() {
    return dailyconsolidated;
}

public void setDailyconsolidated(boolean dailyconsolidated) {
    this.dailyconsolidated = dailyconsolidated;
}

@DynamoDBConvertedBool(DynamoDBConvertedBool.Format.true_false)
public boolean isDailyindividual() {
    return dailyindividual;
}

public void setDailyindividual(boolean dailyindividual) {
    this.dailyindividual = dailyindividual;
}
```

I have given the annotations used and sample attributes used in my class file for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using @DynamoDBTyped annotation ?

```java
@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
```